# Displaying page Name in the URL instead of page ID in yii?

Tags: url, yii, url-rewriting

How to display **Page Name** in the url instead of **Page ID**

For example, It Should be

> localhost/mysite/index.php/page/about

Instead of

> localhost/mysite/index.php/page/1

I have tired from edit actionview()

```
public function actionView($id)
{
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
}
```

Comment: Learn about URL rewriting in `Yii` at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create links to ANY url that you like. The issue is how you deal with the data that is passed.

So in your view, create a link.

```
<a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/mycontroller/view/', array('page'=>'about')); ?>">About Us</a>
```

This will call the controller action actionView(). You can then handle the page in there.

```
public function actionView($page)
{
   // Load the model with the required page tag.
   $pageDetails = Article::model()->findByAttributes(
       array('page_name' => $page)
   );
   // Display the page
   $this->render('view',array(
       'model'=>$pageDetails
   ));
}
```

Answer (score -4):

**Updated Answer**

Hope you are making your website SEO friendly with pretty URL. If your pages are static web pages such as about, faq, privacy..., you can implement the above answer provided by `crafter`. In this case page names should unique.

Another way (but not exactly what you want) is url rewriting with native yii feature `urlManager`. In this case  `page id` will appear in URL like bellow.

> localhost/mysite/index.php/page/1/about
>
> localhost/mysite/index.php/page/2/britain-to-support-italys-intelligence-effort-on-migrants

If you observe, most of the News website following the same url structure.

**Ex:** http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/economics/11682277/Greeks-admit-they-will-default-at-the-end-of-the-month-as-central-bank-turns-on-government.html

To do this this in application, you have to write urlManager rules.

```
    'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>true,            
        'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

            //We are adding pretty url for article                
            'page/<id:\d+>/<title:[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]>' => 'page/view',
        ),
```

**I am assuming bellow is you `Article` database table**

```
        id     title     description       keywords     status
        -------------------------------------------------------
        1      about     some big text     some keys    active
```

Now i am making the URl dynamically

```
        <?php
        //In Controller
        //Fetch articles and send them to view
        $articles=Articles::model()->findAll();
        ?>

        <?php
        //In View
        //Iterate articles
        foreach($articles as $article)
        {
              $id=$article->id;
              $title=$article->title;
         
              //Make structured Url.
              // Replaces all spaces with hyphens and change text to lowercase .
              $titleInUrl= strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $title)); 

              // Removes special chars. 
              $titleInUrl=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $titleInUrl); 
              ?>
              <a href="<?=yii::app()->baseUrl;?>/page/<?=$id;?>/<?=$titleInUrl;?>">$title</a>
              <?php

        }
        ?>
```

You can also change URL pattern as you want. Ex i need url like

> localhost/mysite/index.php/page/about-1

For this i have write/change rule in urlManager as

```
 'page/<title:[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]>-<id:\d+>' => 'page/view',
```

Hope it will help you for your problem.

Comment: Poor answer, does not directly lead to a solution for the OP.

Comment: @crafter - I will try to put some more useful information for about question.

Comment: sorry but staying with no solution

Comment: @OsamaDiab - i have updated my answer. I may help you to solve your problem.